# npm: dependencies vs devDependencies with bundled dependencies

Tags: npm, dependencies, package.json

Using the search I already found some great answers to similar questions, but still I am not sure if I understood it correctly.

From these answers I learned that `dependencies` are required to run the application while `devDependencies` are only required while developing (like unit tests).

But how about this: My application depends on jQuery, but during a build step (with the help of my `devDependencies`), everything is bundled into one file. In this case, should I list jQuery as `dependency` or as `devDependency`?

*To make my point more clear take a module like this:*

```
define(['jquery'], function($) {
  // use jQuery in this module
})
```

Later on, this module will be compiled into somehing like `application.build.js` which then contains this module and the jQuery dependency.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: @gnerkus please see my edit

Answer (score 10):

Since the end result is the same, there doesn't seem to be a definite rule here, but I found a couple of discussions on the matter:

#### If you're building an application

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/520

> A browser app built by [*insert build tool/bundler*] has no runtime node dependencies, and thus all frontend dependencies should be listed as devDependencies. The `dependencies` vs `devDependencies` naming convention stems historically from node being a server side package manager (...) It is as far as I can tell harmless to list frontend dependencies under `dependencies`, but it is wrong.

> (...) as a general recommendation for everyone, move everything into `devDependencies` until it is actually needed under `dependencies`.

#### If you're building a library:

https://github.com/inuitcss/inuitcss/issues/225

> In many frontend projects, all code served to the browser is compiled, there are no runtime dependencies. This would mean that there are no `dependencies`, only `devDependencies` – all dependencies are included in the build done during development.
>
> One could also argue that dependencies are required for development as well, so it would be okay to list everything unter `dependencies`.

> I think the fact that we have the optional distinction indicates a reasonable way to use them. It makes sense (to me) that the `dependencies` designation would represent the 'minimum viable' code to use and as an indicator of what's nonessential for something to work.

> As I see it, anything that goes on to become part of the production code is a `dependency`.

#### Epilogue

Personally, I agree more with the last quote. It makes sense that `dependencies` tells us what *the application code* needs to run, and `devDependencies` what *the developer* needs to build/deploy/whatever the application/library.

One caveat though is that if someone `npm install`s your library to use the bundle as a module in their own application, they will download a lot of `dependencies` they don't actually need.